# How to calculate this integral between a delta function and a uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

in the interval of $[0, 1]$, like as in a CDF, if I want to take the Wasserstein-1 distance between a delta function and a uniform distribution, how can I evaluate this integral?

$$
d_{W1} = \int_0^1 |\delta(x) - U(x)|dx
$$

I am not sure if I phrased the question correctly, but I am currently reading a paper which has a proof that says this should be $\geq 1/4$ and I do not see why that would be the case...

[paper link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.10288.pdf) - the proof in question is in section B.1 of the appendix.

Comment: Note that the Wasserstein-1 distance is defined between the cumulative distributions. By your notation, I have the impression you were working with the densities instead? You can work out the integral exactly and it comes out as 1/2, which is indeed larger than 1/4. But I have the impression the paper tries to demonstrate a more general statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon my comment, I think you confused cumulative distribution with density. Second, you also forgot to take into account that your "delta" is not necessarily centered at $0$. Let's take the general definition of a delta CDF as

$$H_a(x) = \begin{cases}0 \text{, if } x<a \\ 1 \text{, if } x\geq a \\\end{cases} \, .$$

We then look at the Wasserstein-1 distance (assuming $a \in [0,1]$) which is

$$d_{W_1}(H_a,U) =\int_0^1 | H_a(x) - U(x) | dx = \int_0^a | 0- x | dx + \int_a^1 | 1 - x | dx \; .$$

With a bit of work, you can evaluate those integrals to give

$$d_{W_1}(H_a,U) = \frac{1}{2} + a^2-a \; .$$

This quadratic polynomial attains its minimum in $a=1/2$ where it evaluates to $1/4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me to understand. I am curious why you thought that I confused cumulative distribution with density and I assumed the delta was at 0? I stated in my problem that it was a CDF and I made no mention of the delta needing to be around 0. Was there some problem with my notation? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I gues it was I who assumed it from your notation. Usually $\delta$ is used to characterize the density, and when we mention $\delta(x)$ we mean the delta function with peak at $0$. If you want it at another point, you need $\delta_a(x) = \delta(x-a)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you